# Regular expression to allow only two underscores, absence of other special symbols and previous or next character should number or letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next string SOM_P9ERR96M27VP4_PL. The condition is that there should be only two underscores, which should not be at the end or at the start of the string, and this string should not contain other special characters like "*($,", after the underscore, there should be some character and underscores cant follow each other like __.
I have this regexp `/^(?![_])^[^_]*(_[^_]*){2}[^_](|_[a-zA-Z0-9])$/` it meets the requirements except the last one underscores cant follow each other like SOM__P9QTR96M27VP4PL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the pattern to match 2 times the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` followed by an underscore, and the end again the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

That way there can be only 2 underscores in total, not at the start or end and not 2 times after each other.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TpaH0M/1)